# Auto generate sequence column + a look up info column from another list and calculate in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: infopath, lookup-column

I've an issue on calculating lookup value from other list..
I have List called "Product". in that I have column name "ProductCode"(Single line text) and "Unit Price"(number with 2 decimal). I've created a new custom list called "Purchase Form".

In that "Purchase Form" I want to have below:

- A auto sequence column "Purchase ID" which will auto generate as "PO-15-####". The behind number will start from 2001.
- A lookup column of "ProductCode" which will be in Choice mode.
- A column which have "Unit Price" from another list will automatically generated when we choose the "ProductCode".
- The main important column is "Purchased Value" which will calculate [Purchased Qty*Unit Price] and results will be in currency or number. [I will another column called "Purchased Qty"(number).]

I've tried lookup but unable to do the calculate. I need to have a workaround without using any backend commands.

Please help me to guide how to do in SharePoint 2013 or InfoPath 2013 without having workflow involved.